# Nested include directive results in one or more multiply defined symbols found

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker

I'm experiencing a weird linker issue in Visual Studio 2022 (C++). I have the following (CMake) project structure:

```
- src
   - a.cpp
   - main.cpp
- include
   - a.h
   - b.h
   - main.h
CMakeLists.txt
CMakePresets.json
```

Contents of files in the `src` directory:

**a.cpp**

```
#include "a.h"

// nothing besides the include
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "main.h"

int main() {
    func();

    return 0;
}
```

Contents of files in the `include` directory:

**a.h**:

```
#pragma once

#include "b.h"

// nothing besides the include
```

**b.h**

```
#pragma once

void func() {
}
```

**main.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "a.h"
```

Compilation results in two errors:

1. `Error LNK2005: "void __cdecl func(void)" (?func@@YAXXZ) already defined in a.cpp.obj`
2. `Fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found`

Not sure why, but It seems as though `func` is copied twice by the compiler due to the nested `#include` directives (e.g., `main.h <- a.h <- b.h (func definition)`). I'm able to solve the problem by placing `func` in an anonymous namespace like so:

**b.h**:

```
#pragma once

namespace {
    void func() {
    }
}
```

In other words, it appears that as long as `func` has external linkage the program will not compile. Even weirder, if I change `func` to be a template:

**b.h**:

```
#pragma once

template<typename T>
void func(T a) {
}
```

(and, correspondingly, modify the call to `func(something)` in **main.cpp**), the code compiles without problem! Even though a function generated from function template is supposed to have external linkage as well. What is going on here?

Comment: [Don't define things in header files, only declare them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18914328/12002570)

Comment: A template function is implicitly inline. That is one solution to the original problem, make it `inline`.

Answer (score 1):

An `#include` preprocessor instruction expands the content of the included file into the file being processed **before** the compiler compiles the file (phase 4 of the [translation phases](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases), whereas the compilation in itself is phase 7):

- `main.cpp` includes `main.h` which includes `a.h` which includes `b.h` where `func` is defined (as opposed to only declared).
  To the compiler (i.e. post-preprocessor execution), `main.cpp` looks like:

  ```cpp
   namespace {
       void func() {
       }
   }
   int main() {
       func();

       return 0;
   }
  ```

  The `func` symbol gets created during compilation into `main.obj`.
- `a.cpp` also includes `a.h` which includes `b.h` where `func`, like
  previously, is defined.
  Like above, to the compiler, `a.cpp` looks like:

  ```cpp
   namespace {
       void func() {
       }
   }
  ```

Consequence:

When the linker executes, it sees `func` in both `main.obj` and `a.obj`. This, BTW, is not caused by the `#include` directives being nested.

The normal way to solve this problem is to only **declare** functions in header files (.h) and to define/implement them in source files (.cpp). Unless you do something like `#include "b.cpp"`, this should guarantee the symbol is created only once.

---

When you use an unnamed [namespace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace), the scope where `func` is accessible becomes limited to the 1 translation unit where it appears (see definition 3 of the namespace declaration).

If you follow the link to the [unnamed namespace definition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Unnamed_namespaces) section, you will see the mechanism at play depends on the version of C++ you are using.
It will be either:

- Until C++11:

> Even though names in an unnamed namespace may be declared with external linkage, they are never accessible from other translation units because their namespace name is unique.

- Since C++11:

> Unnamed namespaces as well as all namespaces declared directly or indirectly within an unnamed namespace have internal linkage, which means that any name that is declared within an unnamed namespace has internal linkage.

Either way, this solves the issue encountered by the linker.

---

The reason why it compiles successfully when you change `func` to be a template function is a bit more complex to explain:

- A template of a function is **not** a function; a template of a class is **not** a class.
  To become a function or a class, a template needs to be instantiated.
- A template does not get created by the compiler unless it is instantiated. When it is instantiated more than once, identical specializations (i.e. specialization that use the same template parameters) are merged a link time.

All of that is explained in [this article](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates); quote (highlight from me):

> When a class template specialization is referenced in context that requires a complete object type, or when a function template specialization is referenced in context that requires a function definition to exist, the template is instantiated (**the code for it is actually compiled**), unless the template was already explicitly specialized or explicitly instantiated. Instantiation of a class template does not instantiate any of its member functions unless they are also used. **At link time, identical instantiations generated by different translation units are merged**.

In your question, since you only create `func` once, the merging mechanism does not kick in.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem only occurs when the function is **not** placed inside a `namespace`. With `namespace` everything works fine. I guess this is because each anonymous namespace has effectively a unique name, so that to the compiler treats the two definitions of `func` in two anonymous namespaces as two different definitions, correct?

Comment: Let me edit my answer to cover that.

Comment: Using anonymous namespaces in a header is a strange way to solve this problem, just make the function `inline`

Answer (score 1):

It's because both translation units (the one built from `a.cpp` and the one built from `main.cpp`) includes a definition of `func` which violates the [*one definition rule*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule).

The solution is to only *declare* `func` in `b.h`:

```cpp
#pragma once

void func();
```

and *define* it in `b.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "b.h"

void func() {
}
```

Now both translation unit `a.cpp` and `main.cpp` will see the declaration of `func` but only translation unit `b.cpp` will define it - so the one definition rule is not violated anymore.